# How to display live data using Power BI maps with Data Source as SQL Server?

Tags: powerbi

I have two tables under a DB in SQL Server. One table has location-related data, i.e., latitude and longitude. The second table has real-time transactional data. I have a simple join query which pulls in the latest transactions and displays the location of the transaction on the map in Power BI. 
I want to achieve this in Real Time, can anyone tell me if there is a way to do this?

Comment: Do you have a streaming dataset to work with?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. I only have old school DBs SQL Server.

Comment: I don't think this is feasible unless you have a streaming dataset, regardless of your reporting tool.

Answer (score 0):

[DirectQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-directquery-about) connections to your database are the way to get a "live" connection.

Note, however, that this won't automatically refresh itself, but rather will pull the latest data whenever you change a filter/slicer or hit the Refresh button in the pane above the report.

> "Any changes to the underlying data will not be immediately reflected in any existing visuals. It is still necessary to Refresh, whereupon the necessary queries will be resent for each visual, and the visual updated as necessary."

---

To have [real-time streaming data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-real-time-streaming) on a report or dashboard, you need to have an appropriate streaming dataset set up. I don't know how to do this, but it [may be possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-send-data-as-a-stream) with your SQL Server.

Comment: Do you which tool can be used to display live transactional data on maps that best describes my scenario?